# Serverless nodejs skip https request

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, serverless

I want to send a https request and process the result with serverless framework, but it seems not working.

Nodejs (serverless) skip my request and jump directly to the last result without waiting https reponse

here my function:

```
import { APIGatewayEvent, Callback, Context, Handler } from "aws-lambda";
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const querystring = require('querystring');
const https = require('https');

const TOKEN: String = "token";

export const hello: Handler = (
  event: APIGatewayEvent,
  context: Context,
  cb: Callback
) => {
function https_request() {

    var postData = querystring.stringify({
      query: "query"
    });

    var options = {
      hostname: 'example.com',
      port: 443,
      path: '/path',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': TOKEN
      }
    };


    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      console.log("before request")
      var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
        console.log('headers:', res.headers);

        if (res.statusCode !== 200) {

          // REJECT IF THE RESPONSE WASN'T AS EXPECTED
          return reject(new Error('Request failed'));
        }

        res.on('data', (d) => {

          process.stdout.write(d);
          resolve(d); // RESOLVE ON SUCCESS WITH EXPECTED DATA

        });
      });

      req.on('error', (e) => {
        console.error(e);
        reject(e); // REJECT ON REQUEST ERROR
      });

      // req.write(postData);
      req.end();
    }) 

  }
  let x:any;



async function myAsyncF() {
    x= await https_request();
    console.log(x.body)
    return x.body
  }

  myAsyncF()

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: x,
      input: event
    })
  };

  cb(null, response);
};
```

I used the async await, but nothing is returned (i should receive at least an error if there is some king of network error)

here is my output:
before request 
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": "{\"input\":\"\"}"
}

is there something missing ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At no point do you resolve your `Promise`, I've no idea what you deem a "successful" request but here's an example that should get you on the right track

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log("before request")
  var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', res.headers);

    if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
      // REJECT IF THE RESPONSE WASN'T AS EXPECTED
      return reject(new Error('Request failed'));
    }

    res.on('data', (d) => {
      process.stdout.write(d);
      resolve(d); // RESOLVE ON SUCCESS WITH EXPECTED DATA
    });
  });

  req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
    reject(e); // REJECT ON REQUEST ERROR
  });

  req.write(postData);
  req.end();
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but still not working, it skip https.request function, there is no log for statusCode or headers, i receive only before request
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": "{\"message\":\"\",\"input\":\"\"}"
}

Comment: @h.zak that's because in you only seem to return that object in `cb` , you need to get the result from `http_request` and add it to the body of the response if that's what the intention is.

Comment: i added to the body but nothing has changed, i updated the code in my question because i can't put it in the comment

Comment: The problem is resolved using request-promise package, i really don't know what i missed exactly

Comment: @h.zak there were multiple issues in your code e.g. not resolving the promise (which my answer addresses) but then you weren't propagating the result out of `myAsyncF` and then finally you don't await the result of that function either. I think it's probably a bit vague to suggest "using request-promise package" solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove process.stdout.write will is not a great practice as you are running your code on lambda, use a context object or a callback function to return

process.stdout.write(d) is write operation on file, sometimes it silently fails as well, running on EC2, ECS your solution looks gem. But on serverless it's always better to avoid file operation functions